# error in gdata-objectivec-client api + oauth2 ios framework

Tags: iphone, ios, google-api

guys i am doing google docs integration in my iphone app,

i have used the gdata-objectivec-client from http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

and configured my project with this steps http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/

when i create instance of GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h using following code

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;

viewController = [[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                             clientID:kMyClientID
                                                         clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                             delegate:self
                                                     finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

**i got this error missing GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.nib**

please help me , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.nib` file in root project(main project out side the data project)

I was having the same problem, but it was Xcode's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.nib file from SVN url give as http://gtm-oauth2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source/Touch/. Download the file from here and then add it in your project. It will work fine.

Comment: file is already there in Gdata project and included in the project, still it displays error like that. can you provide source for this limbasiya.nirav1@gmail.com

Comment: Check your code and the XIB file properly. Also check the linking of the xib file and the class. I cant provide you the code. It is working in my project.

Comment: i can upload the source, can u correct the error nd send back ?